# Lua - attempt to index local 'collidable' (a nil value)

Tags: lua

[details screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpwTs.png)

[Game screenshot - having fun making it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qveg4.png)
The problematic code is as follows! I have the script on a door sending a vector ray to it but it seems it is not recognizing my character which has correct name: pm_euhyrig

```
isAtPorta = 0

function Behavior:Awake()
end

function Behavior:Update()

local position = self.gameObject.transform:GetPosition()
local orientation = self.gameObject.transform:GetOrientation()
local myRay = Ray:New( position, Vector3.Transform( Vector3:Forward(), orientation ) )
local collidable = CraftStudio.FindGameObject( "pm_euhyrig" )
local distance = myRay:IntersectsModelRenderer( collidable:GetComponent( "ModelRenderer" ) )
if distance ~= nil and distance > 2 then
isAtPorta = 0 end
if distance ~= nil and distance < 2 then
        isAtPorta = 1   
    end 
if isAtPorta == 1 and CraftStudio.Input.WasButtonJustPressed( "pare" ) then
CraftStudio.FindGameObject("porta").modelRenderer:SetAnimation( CS.FindAsset(self.porta1_path) )
CraftStudio.FindGameObject("porta").modelRenderer:StartAnimationPlayback(self.porta1)

    end end
```

Comment: Could you please insert the code in your image as actual text into your question—it would make answering your question much easier.

Comment: oh sure (sorry) just a moment

Comment: Just did it! updated above!

Comment: you can try to add print(collidable) just after local collidable = CraftStudio.FindGameObject( "pm_euhyrig" ) to see if collidable is not nil

Comment: it prints Nil... but that script works if I put it in my character and have the door as the collidable.... and i am sure my character´s name is pm_euhyrig, so I don´t know why it is not finding my character

Comment: oh sorry my bad, in this case the problem comes from CraftStudio.FindGameObject( "pm_euhyrig" ). It can be as you mentioned "pm_euhyrig" OR the function CraftStudio.FindGameObject(...). So to help you debug you can try changing "pm_euhyrig" to somehing you know already works...

Comment: How I wish I could be working, I would def. send donations to helpers.. :( but I´ve been unemployed for over 5 years here in third world Brazil, so I really appreciate your kind help"(s)"! :D - I am having a lot of fun building my little game (non commercial of course)

Comment: ok I will see to look into that! just added my game´s screenshot!

Comment: well, I resorted to putting the collision script on my own character and that worked.
On the door I would not have to write scripts for every door, now I will have..